# How to grant fan page permission to an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have an application i got offline_access and manage_pages perms

i can upload photos by this code:

```
$phototoken='AAAAABya***sZAJ';

$photo_details = array(
    'access_token' => $phototoken
);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($img);
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
}
```

but when i change my password my token will die and my app won't be able to access the to fan page am i right

http://smileychatcodes.com/facebook-smiley-chat-codes/
so how these sites access to fan pages as offline?

Comment: Check the facebook.developer there is an option to generate an longer lasting token.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your password will always invalidate the User Access Token, however as [explained here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#pagetokens) you can get a long-lived User access token which will allow you to generate an infinite-life Page Access Token.